# submit textarea into phpmyadmin issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to submit a text area where user can enter anything or any special characters with the same text format as user input into the text area. Like spaces, new line and tab at the start of the new line. I have one the below codes but when the user input contain ',",(,) it showing the sqlquery error. Please let me know how to insert text like forum into the database.

html is

```
<textarea class="noticearea" name="notice_area" id="notice_area" ></textarea>
```

php is

```
$noticeinsert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notice_board(notice_id, notice_area, notice_dnt) VALUES ('$notice_id', '$notice_area', '$notice_dnt')");
```

please let me know how to submit any enter value into the database. Also, is it safe to send html or php codes or speicial char entered by users into database ?

Comment: this kind of embedding string from variables that are filled with user input content makes you potentially vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: You need to sanitize and escape your inputs. Look into prepared statements.

Comment: can u please explain me clearly

Comment: In this case `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `stripslashes()` etc, but you should look into mysqli/PDO.

Comment: #ben fortune, i saw the above comment that embedding string from varaible are vulnerable if i use mysql_real_escape_string it is also the same problem ??

Comment: yes vulnerability remains, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string to get around this use parametrized/prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `$_POST`.

Change

```
$noticeinsert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notice_board(notice_id, notice_area, notice_dnt) VALUES ('$notice_id', '$notice_area', '$notice_dnt')");
```

To

```
$noticeinsert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notice_board(notice_id, notice_area, notice_dnt) VALUES ('$_POST["notice_id"]', '$_POST["notice_area"]', '$_POST["notice_dnt"]')");
```

But check the `$_POST` variables, because of sql-injection.

Comment: this all variables in the values are cming from $_post only

Comment: this is my post variable $notice_area = $_POST["notice_area"];

Comment: Show us your database schema and more code pls ;) i cannot find a error in the code above..

Comment: This is the only code, when user enter ' in the text area it showing error because it is taking ' as the syntax of the mysql

Comment: use `$notice_area = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notice_area']);` before insert..

Comment: The ' interrupts the SQL statement.

Comment: correct this works... thanks you ... is it safe to enter all the html or special char into the database

Comment: No Problem ;) 
You can read more information here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
 <textarea class="noticearea" name="notice_area" id="notice_area" </textarea>
```

To:

```
  <textarea class="noticearea" name="notice_area" id="notice_area"></textarea>
```

Comment: sorry its just a mistake here i entered the code manually i edited it

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `>` in your html file

Comment: sorry its just a mistake here i entered the code manually i edited it

Comment: first of all check the all the values are getting or not?